# Is it possible for MySQL to order by a certain column but if a value of another column is X put it at the end?

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 tables, `users`, `warnings`, `warningnames`.

The content of the tables is as follows:

Users(simplified):

```
u_id, username, password, rank
```

Warnings:

```
w_id, wn_id, u_reporter_id, u_reported_id
```

Warningnames:

```
wn_id, warningInfo, warningPoints
```

I have a loop in PHP which gets me all users with a simple query:

```
SELECT *
FROM users 
WHERE u_id < :startcount 
ORDER BY u_id DESC 
LIMIT :perpage
```

How do I make a query which gets all users but puts the users with the most warnings at the top and the users with rank 0 at the bottom?

The query I have so far is:

```
SELECT users.*, COUNT(warnings.w_id) as warningCount
FROM users 
LEFT JOIN warnings 
ON users.u_id = u_reported_id 
WHERE u_id < :startcount 
ORDER BY warningCount DESC
LIMIT :perpage
```

But that doesn't return what I want, it just returns the `warningCount` of all users in a single query that fit the `WHERE` statement.

Example fiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ec6c2d/6

Sample PHP code:

```
<?php
$query = $this->handler->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE u_id < :startcount ORDER BY u_id DESC LIMIT :perpage');
try{
    $query->execute([
        ':startcount'   => 25,
        ':perpage'      => 25
    ]);
}
catch(PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

while($fetch = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    echo $fetch['username'] . '<br />';
}
?>
```

How can I correct this and order by a `warningCount` column but put all users with `rank` 0 at the end?

Comment: Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless

Comment: This should be throwing an error when executing. The `:perpage` must be bound as an integer the shorthand `execute` binds everything as strings... unless that changed with 8?

Comment: @user3783243 it doesn't throw an exception for me with PHP 8.

Comment: While undoubtedly 'complete' and 'reproducible', are you sure this data set is 'minimal'?

Comment: What do you mean with 'minimal'?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it, you want to order by warning count, but ignore users with rank = 0 on that query ??
if that's the case, what you need is group by, and then order by using case when,
here's what I came up :

```
SELECT users.*, COUNT(warnings.w_id) as warningCount
FROM users 
LEFT JOIN warnings 
ON users.u_id = u_reported_id 
  WHERE u_id < 10 
group by users.u_id
ORDER BY 
  case when rank = 0 
  then 0 
  else COUNT(warnings.w_id) + 1
  end
DESC
LIMIT 25
```

I add +1 on order by to make sure, users with rank 0 is always at the bottom.

Edit :

- I Add the where startCount and the limit to the query

Comment: That doesn't work properly either, I also need to use `:startcount` and LIMIT by `:perpage`

Comment: @Tom already Add :startcount and :perpage

Comment: It doesn't work, it puts the banned users at the bottom of the first page, I want them to go on the last page.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL Fiddle was helpful in explaining you situation, and I think you're looking for GROUP BY. Also note that you can order by multiple fields.

I've edited your fiddle slightly: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/av9d6ordS9XVpavwzZUs8W/0

```sql
SELECT u.*, COUNT(w.wn_id) warnings
FROM users u
INNER JOIN warnings w ON u.u_id = w.u_reported_id
GROUP BY u.u_id
ORDER BY warnings DESC, u.rank DESC
# LIMIT 10
```

Comment: That doesn't work, in your fiddle not all users with rank 0 are at the bottom, I want all users with rank 0 regardless how many warnings they have to be at the bottom of the result.